# Flutter how to add indent and end indent to app bar?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

[Please check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vyPI.png)

I know about titleSpacing in AppBar but that will only be applied to the title and if I put any leading icon, that won't work for me as expected. My whole screen has a padding of 28 pixels on left and right, which I can do using Padding widget in the Scaffold body. But I am struggling to do the same in the appBar. I don't want to add padding to each icon or title because I have multiple action icons. I only want to add a certain padding to the left of the first element of appBar and same for the last action icon of the appBar.

Comment: Does your `AppBar` never have a background color of its own ?

Comment: How does that matter here? The design I have made for this has a flushed AppBar with rest of the body. No elevation and no color.

Comment: Since, there is a hacky way that can add margin to your `AppBar`, but then `margin` means that your app background color will appear at the right and left of your appbar. Other than this method and creating your own appbar, it seems like it isnt possible from what I checked in source code. it render Row([leading, text, trailing]) and Row can't be given padding, so you can only set individual padding, thats why I was asking.

Comment: I can make the `AppBar` in transparent or white color so it does not matter if the color shows. I couldn't find a way to add Padding or Margin to the `AppBar`, can you help me with that please?

Comment: Added an answer, check it out. You can actually have whatever backgroundColor you want as well. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, it is a tough question to answer whether this approach is suggested or not, but you can basically make your custom appbar with slight changes to original `AppBar`.

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final AppBar appBar;

  CustomAppBar(this.appBar);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(56);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Row(children: [
      SizedBox(width: 16),
      Expanded(child: appBar),
      SizedBox(width: 16),
    ]);
}

class CAE extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: CustomAppBar(AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
      title: Text(
        'Custom App Bar',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
      actions: [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today))
      ],
    )),
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
    ),
  );
}
```

We are basically creating a `Row` that that has a `SizedBox` on each side of the actual `AppBar`.

But since this is just a `Widget` and does not extends `AppBar`, we can't use it in `Scaffold.appBar` directly.

You see, `AppBar` is just a `Widget` that implements `PreferredSizeWidget`. So we make our custom widget implement the same class. For this to work, we need to override the `preferredSize` getter.

From documentation of `AppBar`,

> preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(toolbarHeight ?? 56 + (bottom?.preferredSize.height ?? 0.0)),

which can be simplified to just `Size.fromHeight(56)` and this is what I used in override.

Then, you can basically use your new widget in `Scaffold` like

```
Scaffold(appBar: CustomAppBar(AppBar(/* Whatever your actual AppBar is */)))
```

Output.

[image]

In case you do want to set a backgroundColor, then do wrap then use a `Container` instead of `SizedBox` and then set `color` to it.